# J2ME java target problems?

Tags: java, java-me

I have a largish app in Java to port over to j2me and it's proving quite tedious.

The target java (1.3 I believe) is making porting this over to j2me very difficult.

I'm working in Netbeans and I was wondering if there was a way to change the target java to a higher one to avoid reprogramming tons of classes to comply with 1.3 and if I did change it could I expect it to run on any device?

I've looked around on my IDE and can't find an option to change the target.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the java target of a Java ME app, so you will have to use only what its available from CLDC, but you can try The J2ME Polish Client Framework http://www.enough.de/javadoc/j2me/index.html

Take a look at de.enough.polish.util package.